# How to pass in a public key as a string to an action?

Tags: eosio-code, public-key

I see that `public_key` is

`public_key = std::variant<ecc_public_key, ecc_public_key, webauthn_public_key>`

While `ecc_public_key` is

```
std::array<char, 33>
```

How would I create a public key object from the string `EOS8UibhGUtirJs2j8maECR5UvMwxF661hq9Xo3FpdVcoFxcJXKxE`

Comment: use the contract public_key

Comment: bumping this since I hit this roadblock too. Still couldn't make it work using eosiocdt v1.8.0. I need this since I'm planning to put ECDSA on my contracts so that I can send a signature along with a transaction without the need of cosigning.

Comment: bump again....!